# Unable to push Django project to Heroku

Tags: django

I am getting this error while pushing the Django project to Heroku master. I am new to Django. Any help will be really appreciated.

-----> Installing dependencies using Pip (1.2.1)
       Downloading/unpacking Brlapi==0.5.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
         Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement Brlapi==0.5.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
       No distributions at all found for Brlapi==0.5.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
       Storing complete log in /app/.pip/pip.log
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Python app

To git@heroku.com:enigmatic-plateau-3620.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `--no-site-packages` option to prevent the virtual environment from having access to all the packages on your system.

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages venv
```

If you don't need the Brlapi for your Django app, try removing the Brlapi==0.5.5 line from your `requirements.txt` document.  Then, commit the change:

```
git add requirements.txt
git commit
git push heroku master
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you